# What is the relationship between building blocks and SOA

Tags: soa, buildingblocks

Can anyone explain further about what is the relationship between building blocks and SOA?

SOA is a IT architecture. is building blocks a concept in SOA?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**building blocks** is an analogy how a SOA system is constructed.

The objective is to be able to build SOA Systems from standardised components.